# Create JavaScript Object from string

Tags: javascript, json

Could you please help me to prepare below Object from string using JS. I am new in JS.

```
health status index       uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   new_log jdbc1233q6AiRUSRCczayjz0rw   1   1     603442            0    127.6mb        127.6mb
```

From above string how do I create below object?

```
{
    "health": "yellow",
    "status": "open",
    "index": "new_log",
    "uuid": "jdbc1233q6AiRUSRCczayjz0rw",
    "pri": "1",
    "rep": "1",
    "docs.count": "603442",
    "docs.deleted": "0",
    "store.size": "127.6mb",
    "pri.store.size": "127.6mb"
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+object+from+strings+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: String split is useful

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually only split is not working form me.

Comment: Related: [javascript: convert two dimensional array to array of objects using the first 'row' to define properties](/q/22917269/4642212). You will also need: [`String.prototype.split`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`Array.prototype.map`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`JSON.stringify`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). Where are your attempts? [Edit] the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can use split

```js
const str = `health status index       uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   new_log jdbc1233q6AiRUSRCczayjz0rw   1   1     603442            0    127.6mb        127.6mb`
const lines = str.split(/\n/); // split lines on \n
const arrs = lines.map(line => line.split(/\s+/)); // split line on whitespace
const obj = {}; // define an object, we could use reduce but this is easier to read
arrs[0].forEach((word,i) => obj[word] = arrs[1][i])
console.log(obj); // show it
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // show the JSON
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question, however @mplungjan, till I don't understand why did my question is being as mark as negative?

Comment: @Soma Because you did not show any effort in fixing the issue yourself. Read the [ask] to see how

Comment: Okay, got it. Actually my code is around 2000 lines. And one of line I was getting that string as ES  response which I need to display in Nebular Tabular format. Henceforth was not sure how much should I post with you. For a clean approach I was going for this. Anyway thanks for the help.